# leptonica for enhancing tesseract ocr in android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I'm working on an android OCR project and decided to use tesseract but I have very poor results. I found that leptonica has fairly good features that can help enhancing the results but I can't find any example or documentation about how to use it in android, only there is a documentation of the cpp api, can anyone help me find any resource that can help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be helpful